# Position element inside absolute parent with respect to grandparent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have child element which need to be positioned `absolute` with the grandparent. The problem is that the parent is also positioned absolutely.

I can't use JavaScript. How can I achieve this with just pure CSS?

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w1t25ydb/)**

```
<div class="col-md-6 gp">
    <div class="col-md-4 p">
        <div class="col-md-2 c"> position me w.r.t to .gp</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.gp { height : 200px; position: relative; }

.p {
    height : 100px; width: 250px;
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px; left: 50px;
}

.c { position: absolute; height: 50px; }
```

Comment: Just make a wrapper `div` around the inner `absolute` element and give it `position: relative`.

Comment: Please be more specific on the issue. An example would be excellent.

Comment: @HashemQolami Color me interested. Frankly, if you are positioning relative to a grand-parent it's an argument to restructure the mark-up to my mind and make the grand-child just a child.

Comment: @Paulie_D i do agree with you but this place i had an exception which i could'nt able to do

Comment: @Sebsemillia can you show demo

Comment: @Jason updated with sample example

Comment: I'm not aware of any CSS property that will enable this (it's not the way positioning works). JS is, I suspect, your only recourse...unless the HTML can be restructured.

Comment: @Paulie_D It is possible, I'm about to post an answer.

Comment: Ooohh....waiting...waiting. :)

Comment: @aktiv-coder Looking at your fiddle you are using bootstrap. But use use it wrong, your markup can't work. Fixing this could solve your problem. Also and example of what you want to achieve would be helpful. `position me w.r.t to .gp` is not self-explanatory to me..

Comment: @Sebsemillia w.r.t = with respect to , with div of className gp

Comment: Post your code in your question please. If jsFiddle ever goes away your question becomes instantly worthless.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If supporting Internet Explorer 8 (and below) is not a concern, we could achieve that by pure CSS. Here is what you should know about [CSS Transforms](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms):

> **[6 The Transform Rendering Model](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transform-rendering)**
>
> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any
>   value other than `none` for the transform results in the creation of
>   both a [stacking context](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#x44) and a [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block). The object
>   acts as a **containing block for fixed positioned descendants**.

Hence, we add a `transform` with a value other than `auto` to the *grandparent* element, we will be able to use `fixed` positioning place the *child* element with the respect of the *grandparent* element which is creating the containing block.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/guciwe/1/watch?html,css,output)**

For instance:

```css
.grandpa {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.dad {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px; height: 250px;
  bottom: 4em; left: 4em;
}

.son {
  position: fixed; /* This will be positioned with the respect to the grandpa
                      rather than the viewport */
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  top: 2em; right: 2em;
}
```

Also, CSS Legendary Eric Mayer has written an article about this:

> **[Un-fixing Fixed Elements with CSS Transforms](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/)**
>
> A transformed element creates a containing block even for descendants
>   that have been set to position: fixed.  In other words, the containing
>   block for a fixed-position descendant of a transformed element is the
>   transformed element, not the viewport.

Comment: @Hashem - This is awesome for Chrome and other web-kit browsers, but what do I do if I need this to work in ie9+?

Comment: @toddmo What do you mean it stops working when grandpa is scrolled up and down? It looks like both the son and the dad stay put.

Comment: @IsaacMontaine, I withdrew my comment b/c now in the demo they all scroll together as the body scrolls.

Comment: Excellent answer! But can you update your link from W3C Editor's draft to Working draft? Also this doesn't seem to work even in IE11.

Comment: Is this still valid in 2021?

Comment: Kudos, my friend. this works wonderfully with an intersection observer that is used like a selection tool :) I've been looking for something like this for a while

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really understand what you are asking, but i've edit your css:

```
.gp {
   height : 200px;
   border : 1px solid red;
 }
 .p {
   height : 100px;
   width: 200px;
   border : 1px solid blue;
   position: absolute;
   top : 50px;
   left : 50px
}
.c {
    height : 50px;
    border : 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

you've wrote positioned and not position. Tell me if now it works

Comment: look at hasheem answer , that is what i am trying to achieve