# How to position a div inside an absolute div but in relation to the parent relative div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the html code:

```html
<div data-page="page1" style="position:relative; width:791px; height:1120px;">
  <div style="position:absolute; width:553px; height:34px;border: 1px solid #000; top:242px; left:75px">
      <span style="width:100px; height:17px;top:250px; left:80px;position:inherit;">This is a divTITLE</span>
      <span style="width:100px; height:17px;top:250px; left:100px;position:inherit;">This is a div inherit</span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that I want to position the divTITLE in relation to the ancestor div (page1) and not in relation to the parent div. But, I can't seem to get it right....

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using "position:inherit", it will make spans also use the position:absolute. You should explicitly mention position:relative;. Also use "display:block" when you want an element to take its own row.

```html
<div data-page="page1" style="position:relative; width:791px; height:1120px;">
  <div style="position:absolute; width:553px; height:34px;border: 1px solid #000; top:242px; left:75px">
      <span style="width:100px; height:17px; left:80px;;position:relative;">This is a divTITLE</span>
      <span style="width:150px; height:17px; left:100px;position:relative;display:block;">This is a div inherit</span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `position: fixed;` in place of `position:inherit`.

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768069/position-element-inside-absolute-parent-with-respect-to-grandparent)